# Watson Conversation Global Nodes

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

In Watson Dialog, you could add nodes in the "Global" folder that would be checked first no matter the state of the dialog. We used these to recover when the dialog was stuck or lost. The user was instructed to enter "start over" at any time no matter where in the dialog to reset things and begin again.

Is there a way to do something similar in Conversation?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand Watson Conversation the [dialog nodes are always evaluated top down](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#overview). By default there are a `Welcome` and an `Anything_else` node. For your `start over` you would need to do the following:

- define an intent to catch words for "start over", "begin again" or "reset".
- Have a dialog node with a condition to match that intent, have that node close to the top of the tree
- in that `start_over` dialog node you could process whatever you need, it is also possible to directly jump from there to any other node or just respond with "okay" and then wait for input again

For more complex processing of the `start over` you could also use [nested processing as I have shown in my collection of samples](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/watson-conversation-variables).